# Code style: Reuse of a control expression or control variable in the branch of a switch/if statement

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, switch-statement, coding-style

Recently, I've found a piece of code which looks like this.

```
switch(type)
{
    case TYPE1:
        doSomething1(type, arg1);
        break;
    case TYPE2:
        doSomething2(type, arg1, arg2);
        break;
}
```

Why don't just pass explicitly those enums (TYPE1, TYPE2) instead of passing the **type** variable? Like in the following example.

```
switch(type)
{
    case TYPE1:
        doSomething1(TYPE1, arg1);
        break;
    case TYPE2:
        doSomething2(TYPE2, arg1, arg2);
        break;
}
```

I understand that such repetition is OK when the variable is reused in:

- the default case of switch statement
- multiple merged cases e.g.

```
    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE1:
        case TYPE2:
        case TYPE3:
            someFunction(type, arg1, arg2);
            break;
    }
```

But in the first example it seems to be useless.

What do you think about that? Is there any advantage of such convention?

Comment: C++ is a lot different from C here in that you have tools like proper object-oriented design and function overrides to handle this instead of a dispatch table like this.

Comment: As to your question: maybe the first way avoids typos: `doSomething2(TYPE1, arg1, arg2);`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/briankung/7437607, item 7 (sort of, in a very minor way).

Answer (score 5):

The first snippet is superior to the second one when it comes to maintainability. Imagine you want to change the branch conditions, e.g. invert `TYPE1` and `TYPE2`: with the first snippet, you have two edits, with the second, there are four.

With regard to your interpretation that passing the flag might be "useless": whether the functions invoked from different branches do need the enum flag or not can't be judged from the example you show. If they don't, it's safe to remove the enum from the function signature. But having such a fallthrough

```
switch (type) {
    case TYPE1:
    case TYPE2:
    doSomething(type /*, ... */);
}
```

suggests that there will be another branching in `doSomething` depending on `type`, which probably is unnecessary code duplication and/or a violation of separation of concerns.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Also, it helps us to make less mistakes e.g forget to change one enum.

Answer (score -3):

```
switch(type)
{
    case TYPE1:
        doSomething1(type, arg1);
        break;
    case TYPE2:
        doSomething2(type, arg1, arg2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh Jarod, you wrecked my pithy comment! :)